# Repeated occurrences of value before creating flag

Tags: grouping, stata, repeat

This question is related to [Identify unique levels of categorical variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483213/identify-unique-levels-of-categorical-variable/40483643?noredirect=1#comment68212295_40483643)

I have a dataset as follows:

```
clear
input int(id date) str8 druggroup
1001 18401 "loop"    
1001 18414 "loop"    
1001 18428 "loop"    
1001 18462 "loop"    
1001 18428 "CCB"     
1001 18462 "arb"     
1002 18401 "arb"     
1002 18473 "arb"     
1002 18414 "thiazide"
1002 18428 "thiazide"
1002 18428 "CCB"     
1002 18466 "CCB"     
end
format %td date
```

I want to create a new variable which contains the earliest date for which I have evidence of the use of three separate druggroups for each id.

The rule for defining "evidence of three" is that I want repeat evidence of druggroup 1 occurring again and in addition an occurrence of druggroups 2 and 3. In other words, druggroup 1 will obviously occur once, in the first row, but I want it to occur again. Druggroups 2 and 3 do not need to be repeat occurrences but they both must occur.

The code I have written so far does not take into account that the first occurring drug needs to occur once more after its first occurrence to count as evidence of repeat use.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
bysort id druggroup (date) : gen firstdate = date[1]
format firstdate %td
list
egen group = group(id firstdate druggroup)
bysort id (group date druggroup): gen count_1 = sum(group != group[_n-1])
replace firstdate=date[2] if count_1==1
list
by id: gen start_date=firstdate if count_1==3
format start_date %td
by id : egen start_d=max(start_date)
format start_d %td
list
```

Here is what I actually want:

```
clear
input int(id date) str8 druggroup float(firstdate group count_1 start_date start_d)
1001 18401 "loop"     18414 1 1     . 18462
1001 18414 "loop"     18414 1 1     . 18462
1001 18428 "CCB"      18428 2 2     . 18462
1001 18428 "loop"     18414 1 1     . 18462
1001 18462 "loop"     18414 1 1     . 18462
1001 18462 "arb"      18462 3 3 18462 18462
1002 18401 "arb"      18414 4 1     . 18473
1002 18414 "thiazide" 18414 5 2     . 18473
1002 18428 "CCB"      18428 6 3     . 18473
1002 18428 "thiazide" 18414 5 2     . 18473
1002 18466 "CCB"      18428 6 3     . 18473
1002 18473 "arb"      18414 4 1 18473 18473
end
format %td date
format %td firstdate
format %td start_date
format %td start_d
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution I find nice because it based on prime number. But it works only if you have 3 drugs per id.

```
bysort id druggroup (date) : gen firstdate = date[1] 
egen group = group(id firstdate druggroup) 
bysort id (group date druggroup): gen count = sum(group != group[_n-1]) 
sort id date

replace count = 5 if count == 3 
replace count = 3 if count == 2 
replace count = 2 if count == 1
```

We will calcul the cumulative product on each date (but the first date as you do not want to count the first drug occurence). Once this product is a multiple of 2*3*5, ie 15, it means the three drugs have been taken (plus the first one)

```
bysort id (date) : gen temp_prod = sum(ln(count)) if _n !=1
by id (date) : replace temp_prod = int(exp(temp_prod)) 
gen temp_mod = mod(temp_prod, 15)
bysort id  (temp_mod) : gen start_date = date if _n == 1 
sort id date
drop temp* first count
format %td start_date
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to find the first date for each drug and each patient, and then the second date for the first drug used. There could be a problem if two or more drugs were dispensed on the first day. The implication seems to be that this doesn't happen.

I have to say that I usually need several tries to get the commands exactly right for this kind of problem.

Some `egen` technique used here is explained in Section 10 of at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0055

```
clear
input int(id date) str8 druggroup
1001 18401 "loop"    
1001 18414 "loop"    
1001 18428 "loop"    
1001 18462 "loop"    
1001 18428 "CCB"     
1001 18462 "arb"     
1002 18401 "arb"     
1002 18473 "arb"     
1002 18414 "thiazide"
1002 18428 "thiazide"
1002 18428 "CCB"     
1002 18466 "CCB"     
end
format %td date

local d druggroup 
bysort id `d' (date): gen first = date[1] if _n == 1 
bysort id (date `d') : gen counter = sum(first < .) 
bysort id `d' (date) : replace first = first[1] 
bysort id (first date druggroup) : gen date1 = date[2] if `d'[2] == `d'[1] 
by id: egen date2 = min(date / (counter == 2)) 
by id: egen date3 = min(date / (counter == 3)) 
gen when = max(date1, date2, date3) if !missing(date1, date2, date3) 

sort id date 
format first date? when %td 
l id date `d' first when, sepby(id) 

     +-----------------------------------------------------+
     |   id        date   druggr~p       first        when |
     |-----------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 1001   19may2010       loop   19may2010   19jul2010 |
  2. | 1001   01jun2010       loop   19may2010   19jul2010 |
  3. | 1001   15jun2010       loop   19may2010   19jul2010 |
  4. | 1001   15jun2010        CCB   15jun2010   19jul2010 |
  5. | 1001   19jul2010        arb   19jul2010   19jul2010 |
  6. | 1001   19jul2010       loop   19may2010   19jul2010 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------|
  7. | 1002   19may2010        arb   19may2010   30jul2010 |
  8. | 1002   01jun2010   thiazide   01jun2010   30jul2010 |
  9. | 1002   15jun2010   thiazide   01jun2010   30jul2010 |
 10. | 1002   15jun2010        CCB   15jun2010   30jul2010 |
 11. | 1002   23jul2010        CCB   15jun2010   30jul2010 |
 12. | 1002   30jul2010        arb   19may2010   30jul2010 |
     +-----------------------------------------------------+
```

.

Comment: unfortunately some druggroups do occur on same date. See my question below.

Comment: Answers can change position in a thread, both randomly and in response to voting, so references to "above" and "below" are of limited use. At the time of this writing, I imagine that you are referring to a query in a comment on your **answer**, currently above this one.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've come up with a slightly more straightforward way (as always very happy to be corrected!). But there is one glitch in my method that I would appreciate help with please.

```
bysort id druggroup (date) : gen firstdate = date[1]
format firstdate %td

egen group2 = group(id firstdate druggroup)
bysort id (group2 druggroup date): gen count_1 = sum(group2 != group2[_n-1])

by id: replace firstdate=date[2] if count_1==1    //be careful of ordering here

by id : egen s_d=max(firstdate) 
format s_d %td
```

The problem is the GROUP code. the order of the groups is getting messed up as stata is factoring in alphabetical order if I have two druggroups on the same date. I don't want alphabetical order - I want stata to preserve the order I have arranged the data in for ordering. Is there a way to tell group to stop automatically alphabetically ordering when I have two drug groups on the same date?

EDIT

I haven't managed to figure out how to break ties here yet. This is my workaround, is not perfect but deals with the problem of 'egen(group)' automatically putting its own alphabetical order on druggroups that occur on the same date.

In my workaround, I have taken the second drug that occurs on the same date and changed its date to date+1. This allows me to preserve the ordering and still seems to achieve the correct result.

The objective here is to make a new date variable; the date should be the earliest date that I have evidence of 3 medicines after the occurrence of the first medicine (so need the first drug to occur again after its first occurrence, but two others to occur).

Code and new sample data below.

```
clear
input int(id date) str8 druggroup byte tag
1001 18401 "loop"     1
1001 18414 "loop"     2
1001 18428 "loop"     2
1001 18428 "CCB"      2
1001 18462 "loop"     2
1001 18462 "arb"      2
2002 18401 "thiazide" 1
2002 18401 "arb"      2
2002 18428 "CCB"      2
2002 18428 "thiazide" 2
2002 18466 "CCB"      2
2002 18473 "arb"      2
3003 18401 "BB"       1
3003 18401 "arb"      2
3003 18428 "BB"       2
3003 18428 "CCB"      2
3003 18466 "CCB"      2
3003 18473 "arb"      2
end
format %td date
```

*make date_copy var

```
gen date_copy= date
replace date_copy=date+1 if date==date[_n-1] & tag[_n-1]==1
format date_copy %td
bysort id druggroup (date_copy) : gen firstdate = date_copy[1]
format firstdate %td
list
sort id date tag
list
```

*getting groups and new count

```
egen group = group(id firstdate druggroup)
bysort id (group date druggroup): gen count_1 = sum(group != group[_n-1])
list 

by id : replace firstdate=date[2] if count_1==1
list

by id : egen s_d=max(firstdate) 
format s_d %td
list
```

Comment: You need to define an observation number variable, say `gen long obsno =_n` and use that to control how ties are broken.

Comment: as explained here?  http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/groups-by-first-occurrence/

Comment: Explained in hundreds of places! You don't need context in this case, just to `generate` that variable and use it.

Comment: still haven't figured out how to break ties, have come up with a dirty workaround instead which I have included as an edit in my "answer". Do you think this might be ok?

Comment: You have to be the judge of "OK".

Comment: ... except that arbitrary changes to the data never get my vote!

Comment: cue existential crisis. I realise its not ideal. At best its pragmatic, at worst.... dirty. But can't figure out how to do it with ties. I know you said this is explained in loads of places - but if you know of one post where it is dealt with in a really easy to understand way would you mind sending me the link please? Thanks again for all your help :)

Comment: It's just this: `sort a obsno b` or `bysort a (obsno b):` where in breaking ties on `a` (a placeholder for one or more variables) you want original order of observations  `obsno` to sort observations ahead of sorting on `b` (a placeholder for zero or more variables).